# Getting HTML data from php page

Tags: php, html, facebook, web-scraping, file-get-contents

I have a URL like this `https://facebook.com/5` , I want to get HTML of that page, just like view source.
I tried using `file_get_contents` but that didn't returned me correct stuff.
Am I missing something ?

Is there any other function that I can utilize ?

If I can't get HTML of that page, what special thing did the developer do while coding the site to avoid this thing ?

Comment: What error do you get with `file_get_contents`? If that function isn't blocked it will return you whatever the server replied. Maybe server is expecting some specific headers, user-agent string or cookies which you are not providing.

Comment: If the HTML is changed after page load, `file_get_contents()` won't pick that up, it just gets the response from the server, it won't run it. Also, there are ways of detecting scripts, often simply by checking the UA against known defaults and returning differing or empty responses. What stuff are you actually getting vs what are you expecting.

Comment: I think your `file-get-contents()` might not support SSL.

Comment: @fMarki555 sometimes I get security captcha HTML for facebook and sometimes I get some JS but not actual HTML

Comment: @JonStirling I agree there must be some headers involved in this, but can you help me in trying that what those headers could be.I am expecting the exact HTML that a user see by doing VIEW SOURCE in browser

Comment: @SmartMindx What are you actually trying to accomplish? Sounds kinda "phishy" to me, if you get my drift...

Comment: @Mike in short I just want the HTML :)

Comment: @SmartMindx Did a quick test. The first hurdle looks to be a simple browser check, you'll need to use the stream context param in file_get_contents to set the UA to something used by a standard browser.

Comment: Scraping Facebook content is against their ToS. If you want to interact with any content on Facebook, use their API.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use curl instead: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

Edit:
Here is an example of mine:

```
$url = 'https://facebook.com/5';
$ssl = true;
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 3;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $ssl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Note that depending on the websites vhost configuration a slash at the end of the url can make a difference.

Edit: Sorry for the undefined variable.. I copied it out of a helper method i used. Now it should be alright.

Yet another Edit:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

By adding this option you will follow the redirects that are apperently happening in your example. Since you said it was an example I actually didnt run it before. Now I did and it works.

Comment: I have tried curl as well but couldnt get actual result.

Comment: As it is, this is more of a comment than an answer. Try adding some actual code.

Comment: @JonStirling No you can't. You need to post questions or answers until you have enough rep to comment.

Comment: @DonL , the code didnt run because $ssl at line # 9 is undefined !

Comment: @DonL , nothing echoed in $data variable, do you get something

Answer (score 0):

**Warning for being off topic**
But does this task **have be done** using PHP?

Since this sounds like a task of web-scraping, I think you would gain more use in [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/).
With this, you can target with precision what you would want to retrieved from the fb-page rather than grabbing the whole content, which I assume as of this writing is generated by multiple requests of content and rendered to you through a virtual DOM.

---

Please note that I haven't tried retrieving content from facebook, but I've done this with multiple services.

---

Good luck!